# How to make calls from a remote computer through my land-line phone?

Tags: voip, phone

I have a great land-line phone plan; I barely use all of the minutes.

Is possible to add a modem/server system so that I can make calls through this line via the internet when I am away? What kind of hardware would I need to make phone calls remotely using my land line?

I don't mind using linux, and access from a smartphone would be a plus.

Answer (score 2):

You can run an asterisk server and connect the telephone line to it with an FXO device like [linksys 3102](http://www.voiptalk.org/products/Linksys+SPA+3102)

EDIT after comment: you connect the 3102 to the asterisk server or to a router with an ethernet cable (like any computer to make a LAN).

For the computers in the LAN you can use a softphone like [twinkle](http://www.xs4all.nl/~mfnboer/twinkle/index.html) for linux or X-lite for windows or you can use a sip phone or a regular phone with an ATA (FXS) (3102 has a FXS too so it can be used).

For remote computers, in my opinion, the best would be to build a VPN and connect to your server and place the call as if you were in LAN).
For smartphones, you can find SIP clients that will work with asterisk easily.
You can also use your asterisk server on a public IP and connect directly without the VPN but you will need to secure it or a lot of people will place calls on your line...

Comment: what do i use to conect to the asterisk server ?

Comment: Edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't sound too difficult. You can use an ISDN-modem or similar as PCI or USB device. [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) could be what you're looking for. You can have it as a software package for many common linux distribution as well as a standalone installation in its own distro.

Skype has an API if I'm not mistaken. Therefore you could make calls out to a number or similar too.

Comment: what do i use to conect to the asterisk server and place the calls?

Comment: here in Switzerland as well as in Germany, the make "Fritz" is well known. AFAIK you can use any ISDN card on a PCI-slot.